# Android - How can I animate different images smoothly?

Tags: android, animation

Can anyone tell me how I can animate different images?  I want to animate different image after some time in my app.
I am new, so please help me or provide me some working example code.

I want to make a program which rotates the images (i.e. one image loads after that 2nd comes to load, but the loading is done like in games where the background images are changed when the player moves).

Comment: please make your question more clear....what exactly you want....???

Comment: hi dinesh i wana make a program which rotate the images i.e means one iamge loads after that 2nd come to load on but the loading is done like in games the background images are changed when the player moves

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code from the API

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/animation/index.html

Check these Links too:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b1e17InAx_w

http://developingthedream.blogspot.com/2011/01/android-canvas-frame-by-frame-animation.html

http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=343

Answer (score 1):

there are multiple ways of animation... 
the most basic one is by the use of Animation framework available in Android.
All you need to do is define the animations in xml and play animation on different imageviews.

you can get sample in API Demo app.

Comment: thanks abhinava can you please send me some working code or example so i can try it as m new so i cant they cant work for me :(